# Python Nested if in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Hi so assume I have a list comprehension

```
mynewdictionary = {key: ([value[0], value[1].strip('Bat')] if 'Bat' in value[1] else value) for key, value in myoriginaldictionary.iteritems()}
```

So what this does, looks at `myoriginaldictionary` if it finds `'Bat'` in `value[1]` since value is a list that has two items and I care only for the second item, and if it does have `'Bat'`, append the key to my new dictionary.

But I want to do a nest if statement.

I want to add, if `len(value) > 0` then do all that, if not skip.

```
myolddictionary= {[key1: 'Bat I am'], ['Key2': 'I am nothing'], [key3: '']}

mynewdictionary={[key1: 'I am'], ['Key2': 'I am nothing']}
```

Comment: That's a dict comprehension btw.

Comment: `.strip('Bat')` does not do what you think it does. It removes *all* `B`, `a` and `t` characters from the start and end of the string: `'taB something Bta'`.strip('Bat')` becomes `' something '`.

Comment: your `myolddictionary` and `mynewdictionary` are not valid `dicts`.

Comment: And your input and output make no sense; did you mean `{key1: ['Bat I am'], ...}` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want something like this?:

```
mynewdictionary = {key: ([value[0], value[1].strip('Bat')] 
                         if 'Bat' in value[1] else value) 
                        for key, value in myoriginaldictionary.iteritems() 
                        if value}
```